# Enough to remove a view from superview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm having a view with an animation in it. When a button is clicked, the view get added like this:

```
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

And when I want the view to disappear, I just run:

```
self.view.viewWithTag(tag).removeFromSuperview()
```

My question is, when the view is removed, does it get deallocated? I feel like, but only in the simulator, that my other UI actions are slower and a bit laggy. I suspect that the animation is still running in the removed view?

Comment: `addSublayers` ? Did you mean `addSubview` ?

Comment: Yea ofc, sorry ;o)

Comment: Corrected, thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 0):

If it is instance variable then it will not be deallocated if it have any reference or it is strong. It's removed from superview but exists in memory untill class is exists. it you declare and init it as local then it will get deallocated i think!

Comment: you can set `yourview = nil`!!!!!!!! if you are using `arc` then you not need to deallocate anything manually. otherwise in old days in `non arc` projects there is method `release` for that!!

Comment: An object gets deallocated when there are no more strong references to the object. That's it. You can use an instance variable and still have it deallocated if the ivar is weak and there are no other references.

Comment: yeah if there is not strong reference then it will deallocated but if it have no reference!

Comment: It doesn't help nill'ing it, weak doesn't either. If I stop the animation in the view before removing it, it runs fine afterwards.